# contact form 7 won't send email after 4.4.2 update

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

suddenly my wordpress site won't send emails after the updating the contact form 7 to 4.4.2. When testing it says the mail was sent successfully, but I do not receive the email. Also after checking in the backend it is stored in the Contact DB, so why all of a sudden is it not sending the emails. I've checked a few wordpress questions about the same thing but unfortunately are outdated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a send email address ? And is it real address? Also is the email a general email address or is it like "email@yourdomain.com"

Comment: yes,yes and donotreply@mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did,

I install this plugin "Easy WP SMTP" and setup my smtp setting there. I make sure my email is same with contact form 7 email. After I tested, it worked.

Then I tested at the front site. It worked too.

Hopefully it helped

Comment: Thanks, Ill keep that info, but after steadily working with it , I was able to realize that the theme I was using was not compatible with the contact form after updating, so I just changed the theme